# Create Procedure Permission ONLY

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a requirement in SQL Server 2008 in development database

1. Only DBA's ( who are database owners ) can create, alter tables .
   Developer's should not create or alter tables .
2. Developers can create/alter Stored Procedure/User Defined functions
   in dbo schema and can execute SP/UDF.
3. Developers should have SELECT,INSERT,DELETE,UPDATE on tables (
   tables in dbo schema

How to achieve this using GRANT statement

---

Found a sample solution from Google, but still have issue

```
CREATE LOGIN testdev WITH PASSWORD = 'sldkjlkjlkj 987kj//'

CREATE USER testdev

GRANT ALTER ON SCHEMA::dbo TO testdev
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO testdev
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON SCHEMA::dbo TO testdev

CREATE TABLE mysig (a int NOT NULL)
EXECUTE AS USER = 'testdev'
go

CREATE PROCEDURE slaskis AS PRINT 12
go

CREATE TABLE hoppsan(a int NOT NULL) -- FAILS!
go

INSERT mysig (a) VALUES(123)
go

REVERT
go

DROP PROCEDURE slaskis
DROP TABLE mysig
DROP USER testdev
DROP LOGIN testdev
```

The syntax above able to block developer to create table but cant block developer to use SSMS design and alter the table.

Thanks.

Comment: first of all do you have separated groups for dba's and developers?

Comment: If you post code or XML, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code" button (101 010) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: hgulyan: yes, i did have different user group for dba & developers

Answer (score 9, accepted):

First of all I would use Roles instead of granting access directly to users. You may be already doing this, but I thought I would mention it.

Okay, the problem here is granting ALTER to the Schema means that the grantee has ALTER access to all object types in the schema. Unfortunately, as far as I know, there is no way to grant permissions to specific object types so it is all or nothing. Conversely, you cannot grant ALTER to all objects and then deny ALTER to specific object types.

The only way I have found to do this is to grant ALTER to the schema and then used a DDL Trigger to control what the role can do.

Here is an updated version of your example demonstrating the principle:

```
--** Create a Developer Role
CREATE ROLE [Developer] AUTHORIZATION db_securityadmin;
GO

--** Grant view and execute on all SPs to Devloper
--GRANT VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::dbo TO [Developer];
GRANT CREATE PROCEDURE TO [Developer];
GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, ALTER, EXECUTE, VIEW DEFINITION ON SCHEMA::dbo TO [Developer]

--** Create user and login for testdev and add to the Developer role
CREATE LOGIN testdev WITH PASSWORD = 'sldkjlkjlkj987kj' 
CREATE USER testdev 
EXEC sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'Developer', @membername = 'testdev';
GO

--** Create DDL trigger to deny drop and alter to the Developer role
CREATE TRIGGER tr_db_DenyDropAlterTable_Dev 
ON DATABASE 
FOR DROP_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE 
AS 
BEGIN 
   IF IS_MEMBER('Developer') = 1 
   BEGIN 
       PRINT 'You are not authorized to alter or drop a table.'; 
       ROLLBACK TRAN; 
   END; 
END; 
GO

--** Testing
CREATE TABLE mysig (a int NOT NULL) ;

EXECUTE AS USER = 'testdev'; 
GO

CREATE PROCEDURE slaskis AS PRINT 12; 
GO

CREATE TABLE hoppsan(a int NOT NULL); -- FAILS! 
GO

INSERT mysig (a) VALUES(123); 
GO

ALTER TABLE mysig ADD test INT; --** This will fail too
GO 

REVERT; 
GO

DROP PROCEDURE slaskis ;
DROP TABLE mysig ;
DROP USER testdev;
DROP LOGIN testdev;
DROP ROLE [Developer];
DROP TRIGGER tr_db_DenyDropAlterTable_Dev on DATABASE;
```

Comment: Just found out that user are able to rename the table name.

can we block or deny user using sp_rename?

Comment: Ah yes, sp_rename. Well if you are running SQL Server 2005, I'm not sure there is much you can do. However in SQL Server 2008 they added the RENAME DDL event, so you can change your DDL Trigger to capture it. So the DDL Trigger becomes: CREATE TRIGGER tr_db_DenyDropAlterTable_Dev ON DATABASE FOR DROP_TABLE, ALTER_TABLE, RENAME AS BEGIN....

Comment: This does not prevent a user from doing "TRUNCATE TABLE [table]". This cannot be stopped with a DDL trigger.

Answer (score -1):

The following Code will Create the user and role in sql server 2012 :

```
 USE PermissionDB; 
 ---Select Your database
 CREATE ROLE Employee;
 ---Create role
 CREATE USER Employee1 Without Login;
 ---Create User

 ----Execute the Above query
 EXEC sp_addrolemember @rolename = 'Employee', @membername = 'Employee1';
```

Hope This would be helpful....

Comment: This is not an answer.  Question specified "Developers should not create or alter tables" and the user in your example could do either.